# How do I edit a contract already in the blockchain?

Tags: dapps, contract-deployment

I have a contract currently in the chain and I want to add a feature. Do I need to make a brand new contract, or is there a better way? 
And if I have registered the contract with a name can I transfer it to the new contract?